# How to use variable as a class name in Mustache/HAML template

Tags: javascript, haml, mustache, hogan.js

I've got the following block of code in my HAML template

```
%strong.meta-value
    %i.tiny-icon-{{ source }}
    {{ source }}
```

If `source: 'foo'` I want the following output:

```
<strong class="meta-value"><i class="tiny-icon-foo">Foo</i></strong>
```

But Rails starts shouting syntax errors at me instead :)

Comment: I think you'd need to use normal attributes, e.g., not the `.class-name` sugar, since you're trying to build up a string.

Comment: Yep, that works so I'll just go with it. Thanks